# Track user details and the pages accessed by him in Salesforce Communities

Tags: apex, community, customer-community, customer-portal, partner-communities

I am working on a POC where i need to capture the pages(standard and vf pages) that are frequently using by an community user.

i am thinking the approach would be google analytics but i don't know it works or not.

it would be very helpful if you could suggest me the solution fot it

Thanks,
Raghav.

Comment: I think that you can get this functionality from reports and dashboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with google analytics, which allows you to track page views.

[Documentation link](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/206/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/communities_google_analytics.pdf)

To do this you need a Google Analytics account and then to add the Analytics Id to the Community using the Community Builder.

The [Community Search Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/comm_search_basics) trailhead module includes getting started with Google Analytics.

To report on this in Salesforce you need the G[oogle Analytics for Salesforce Communities](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/gallery/#posts/search/%3F_.term%3Dsalesforce%26_.start%3D0%26_.type%3DCUSTOM_REPORT%26_.viewId%3DWGfCUMyAT0CaxBM0wOFRsQ/) package on the Google Analytics Gallery.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your reply. I have already configured this using the above links. but what i need is different i want that data into salesforce so that we can categorize the user base on the pages access by the user etc.

Comment: You will need the Google Analytics for Salesforce Communities package from google. https://analytics.google.com/analytics/gallery/#posts/search/%3F_.term%3Dsalesforce%26_.start%3D0%26_.viewId%3DWGfCUMyAT0CaxBM0wOFRsQ/

Comment: I think that Dave is right, you can find more information here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_google_analytics_setup.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

I think that this might help you
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_reporting_dashboards_package.htm&type=0

Along with google analytics, you simply add the google analytics trackingId 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_google_id.htm&type=5